# Is there an active fiddle for ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

According to fiddles.io, there's an environment for experimenting with ElasticSearch at https://www.found.no/play -- but this tool appears to no longer be active.

Is there another place where someone can try ElasticSearch queries online?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Chrome's ElasticSearch Head plugin. It allows to browse your indexes very easily and to test and run some ad-hoc queries.

Please find snippet of such a query below:

```
 {
    "query": {
    "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "customerId": "222333"
              }
            }
          ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, kibana console tools is great too: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/console-kibana.html

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I have found so far is the [free/hobby version of Bonsai](https://bonsai.io/pricing/hobby).

Although, there are restrictions - you cant run all admin commands like  `_cluster` etc. I have been using it for quite some time now - had no issues and its good to play around or test any features.

[image]